Why is Channel 4 (UK) not including S4 E7 of Bones?
I'm working my way though Bones on Channel 4's streaming service and I noticed that S4 E7 is missing.

Why is this episode, "The He in the She", not available?
(The online resources I found don't make any reference to this episode being dropped. The episode synopsis didn't seem particularly controversial compared to the other stuff that goes on in this show.)

A user on Reddit  contacted Channel 4 and received the following response.

“due to an issue with this particular episode, it has since been removed from our streaming platform nor will it be added in the future”.

No additional details were given, but this indicates at least that this was an intentional removal, not simply an error.

If I had to guess, they've likely removed it because of complaints about the episode containing what they consider to be transphobic language. They have significant past form for doing this with older shows where complaints have been received.

Graham Linehan slams Channel 4 for removing transphobic IT Crowd episode

Channel 4 and BBC remove Russell Brand shows including QI, Bake Off and Joe Wicks podcast from their streaming services


